# When responsive mode icons not come properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]

Hi, I have a problem with responsive. When it's responsive mode I need 4 icons in single line. Same like web mode. Please help. I added code in image.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs first"> 

<li class="active" style="padding-right: 15px;"> 
<a href="#Mala" data-toggle="tab"> 
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Malaicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144"> 
<br>Mala Connect</a></li> 

<li style="padding-right: 15px;">
<a href="#LaalsaApp" data-toggle="tab"> 
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/laalsaappicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144"> 
<br>Laalsa App</a></li>
</ul>

<li style="padding-right: 15px;">
<a href="#Toran" data-toggle="tab"> 
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/toranicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144"> 
<br>Toran</a></li>
</ul>

<li style="padding-right: 15px;">
<a href="#Web" data-toggle="tab"> 
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/webicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144"> 
<br>Web</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share code or setup fiddle

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-tabs first">

<li class="active" style="padding-right: 15px;">
<a href="#Mala" data-toggle="tab">
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="https://laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Malaicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144">
<br>Mala Connect</a></li>

<li style="padding-right: 15px;"><a href="#LaalsaApp" data-toggle="tab">
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="https://laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/laalsaappicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144">
<br>Laalsa App</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @media css. Try this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .icons-parent-elements-class{
   display:inline-block;
   width:25%;
   float:left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please see my code in image. This code is not working please help

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-tabs first">

<li class="active" style="padding-right: 15px;">
<a href="#Mala" data-toggle="tab">
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="https://laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Malaicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144">
<br>Mala Connect</a></li>

<li style="padding-right: 15px;"><a href="#LaalsaApp" data-toggle="tab">
<img style="padding-bottom: 15px;" src="https://laalsa.com/business/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/laalsaappicon.png" alt="" width="144" height="144">
<br>Laalsa App</a></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you have to change the width of each element to the number of elements divided by 100%. for example:

```
@media (min-width: 750px){
  .icons-parent-elements-class {
     width: 25%;
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please see my code in image. This code is not working please help

Comment: You have to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your li elements

Answer (score 0):

HTML:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
            <img src="pathnameofimage.png">

        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <img src="pathnameofimage.png">

        </div>
        <div class="div3">
            <img src="pathnameofimage.png">

        </div>
```

for mobile screens use

CSS:-

```
 @media(max-width: 767px){
    .container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please see my code in image. This code is not working please help

Comment: i have edited the post follow this structure inside div1,div2,div3 whatever you want to put can put there

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .nav-tabs.first li {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 8px !important;
  }
            
  .nav-tabs.first li a img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80px !important;
    height:  auto!important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

please try it. if don't work then please share your code. and also remove the height and width form the image tag. these are creating  problem in the responsive view.